# Workaround for Segments not working in Dashboards

Tags: google-analytics, report, dashboard, segments

I was looking to create dashboards for my org's stakeholders for their specific areas of our site. I was unable to get a report for the data I needed, so I researched Segments, created & applied them, and then applied them to each specific Dashboard I created. I come back the next day and noticed that the Segments were not saved in any Dashboards. This turned out to be a big waste of time and now I'm back at where I started with ZERO results to show. GA help pages are a waste of time b/c they don't give you instructions on how to accomplish anything, only why it's important. Can anyone direct me or provide instructions on how I can pull and save a custom report to a Dashboard for a specific area of a website.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address seeing a Google Analytics Segment in a Dashboard is to create a new View using the Segment rules. Once you have a new View, every report and Dashboard will be looking at just the data for the Segment used to create the View. Please note: A new View will only start capturing data from the point of creation and it will not have any of the historical data available. [Create new View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWXwW.jpg)

The other method is to create a new Custom Report and apply a Filter that matches your Segment rules. Then view the resulting report and click on Add to Dashboard. This will preserve your Filter applied. [Custom Report Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8UJU.jpg)

Comment: Thank for so much for your reply and example. Unfortunately, this doesn't alleviate the issue at hand. I am still unable to get any custom reports to work and I'm looking for a instructional walk-through or some type of rubric that clearly shows how to pull custom reports. I've searched over and over again and I can't find this info anywhere!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the Metrics, Dimensions and Segment Rules you are looking at? Example: Metrics = Sessions, Transactions, Conversion Rate. Dimensions = Day of Week Name, Hour of Day, Browser Type. Segment/Filter = ga:country==Australia Note: I use Query Explorer to test the results of a potential Custom Report. [link] (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)